# Can't scrape span tag python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape this url https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5259113/anies-usai-diklarifikasi-polisi-penjelasan-saya-jadi-laporan-23-halaman. And what I want to scrape is string on `span` tag.
[image]

I want to scrape "293" string from that url. But the result is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'` error. And even I'm using find() on `div` tag above that `span` tag and print it, the result is `None`. This is my code:

```
sol = ('https://news.detik.com/berita/d-5259113/anies-usai-diklarifikasi-polisi-penjelasan-saya-jadi-laporan-23-halaman')

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(sol)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")

html2 = driver.page_source
soupa = BeautifulSoup(html2)

ala = soupa.find('span', {'class','comment__cmt_count_komen___12bbw'}).text
print(ala)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wait until comments number set:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.komentar > span')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: element.text != '0 komentar')
print(element.text.rstrip(' komentar'))
```